# css image not showing up

Tags: html, css

i'm new to css and html.
i had something like this and i don't get the background-image show up

```
...
<style type="text/css">
    #header_contain{
width:935px;
height: 135px;
background-image: url('bg.gif') repeat-x;
background-color:#E42323;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header_contain">
    <h4>haga</h4>
</div>
</body>
...
```

I checked the image location and it's alright. I put an image from google and it shows. Now it only shows the bg colour. How can i get the bg image show up?

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome or Safari? If so, lookup the built-in developer tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Once you have them active, right click the #header_contain element and hit "inspect element". This will show the CSS applied, that should help you research the problem, it's hard to tell just fromt he code you posted.

Comment: If the image location is good (same folder as the file provided above) you might some issues with the height? You are stretching it to the right. So a 1px high image would be nearly invisible.

Comment: the path to the image is not relative to the site's root but on the other hand to the css files path, so is you image in the same directory as your css file?

Comment: make sure that you have the bg.gif in the same folder as your css file , if you can post your folders structure this will help (or a link to your files)...also , make sure of the image name (bg.gif , bg.png...) ?

Comment: Try to change it to `background:#e42323 url(bg.gif) repeat-x;` instead.

Comment: That's okay. I followed what the answer did and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your css to this:

```
#header_contain{
width:935px;
height: 135px;
background-image: url('bg.gif');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color:#E42323;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your browser right click on the element and choose `inspect element` .
In the open window find your element properties and find its background url.
If the url is not correct you will see a tooltip `Failed to load the url`.

### firefox  firebug

in the firefox browser, open the firebug plugin and change to `console` tab, reload the page.
You will see the http requests there. If the browser fail to open the Url, you will see an error at console.

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` property value should contain image URL only while you have `repeat-x` too.

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
background-image: url('bg.gif');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color:#E42323;
background-position: left top;
```

You need to undstand all this things like

"background image" is the tag in which you can add image.
"background-repeat" this is help you to repeat the image in x and y axis
"background-color" is help you in fill the color 
"background-position" will help you in change the position of image in px , em etc.
so over code can be in this way as wel "`background: url('bg.gif') #fff left top repeat-x ;`"